# Is the "half-goddess" Hel distinct among mythical rulers of the underworld?

Tags: greek, norse, sumerian

By this I mean, there is a definite parallel between Hel and other underworld goddesses, [Kore/Persephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persephone) in particular, although the concept may be extended to Inanna/Geshtinanna, who Gaiman regards as the same personage in [Ishtar/Belili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishtar#Descent_into_the_underworld).

In the conception of Hel, she actually *embodies* the binary, being "half alive, half dead", where in the Greek and Mesopotamian versions, the underworld aspect is distinct from the regenerative aspect.

---

Related:

We see some reference to regeneration per her presumed ability to resurrect Balder, and also in the idea that "gifts are sent back to Frigg and Fulla by Balder's wife Nanna as from a friendly kingdom" (Davidson?), but is Hel related to Freyja per [Frejya's awesome regenerative power](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/2444/2892)? I find it notable that Freyja also presides over a selection of the dead.

Comment: Freyja seems to be most close to Inanna, I don't see parallel between Hel and Inanna.

Comment: @rus9384 Absolutely.  Freyja/Inanna are associated with beauty, love, fertility and war, but also with death.  Here I'm trying to explore the underworld counterparts of these heavenly aspects of the goddess.